# PHPMailer No Reply

Tags: php, email, mailer

I upgraded my mailing method from my form to phpmailer, and first question is:

Is this all I need for the code? (It does appear to be working) Not sure if I should be using SMTP or not.

```
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = $display;
//$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");
$mail->FromName = 'UMVA Membership Form';
$mail->Host = 'www.umvaonline.org';
$mail->AddAddress('matthew_stacey@ymail.com', "Matt Stacey");
$mail->AddAddress('jskippy@roadrunner.com', "Jacqueline Bennett");
if ($fname2 !="") {$mail->Subject = "UMVA Membership Update ". $fname . " and " . $fname2 . " " . $lname;}
else {$mail->Subject = "UMVA Membership Update " . $fname . " " . $lname;}
$mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Your info has been submitted!<br /><br />";
}
```

2nd question: The email is going to myself and one other person from the form. How do I set the ReplyTo to NONE or No Reply? There's noone to reply to basically as the message is coming from root user and there are no email accounts on the server? Thanks!

Comment: YOu can't set a "no reply" - if there's no `Reply-To` in the email, the `From` will be used instead. This is part of the SMTP RFCs and cannot be avoided. Just do whateveryone else does, and use `some-fake-address-that-wont-get-read@yoursite.com`, e.g. `no-reply@example.com`.

Comment: I thought of something else, the message doesn't need to be in html, so how would I code that so it's just $mail->Msg = $body; (pseudocode)